# Need Power BI recursive formula to refer previous row same column value. Attached is the screenshot

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Need Power BI recursive formula to refer previous row same column value. Attached is the screenshot
[image: power bi recursion formula needed]

calc_amt (column J) is the column for which recursion formula needs to be applied. I have mentioned the fomula description in the formula to column (column K)

I need Power BI Dax formula to calculate calc_amt column

Comment: This may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoiAGB9rQG0